# traffic light sequence animation javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I've been trying to complete a task that was assigned to me.

(iii) Describe the structure of an array that could be used to handle the traffic light sequence.

(iv) Write a script that uses the array described in part `(iii)` to produce an animation of a set of
traffic lights such that the lights change in the standard sequence each time the button is
clicked.

This is what I have.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <img id="RedLight.png" onclick "changeImage()" src="RedLight.png" width="200" height="300">
  <p>Traffic light animation.</p>
  <button type="button" onclick="changeImage()">Change Lights</button>
  <script>
    function changeImage() {
      var image = document.getElementById("RedLight.png");
      if (image.src.match("RedLight.png")) {
        image.src = "RedAmber.png";
      } else if (image.src.match("RedAmber.png")) {
        image.src = "GreenLight.png";
      } else if (image.src.match("GreenLight.png")) {
        image.src = "AmberLight.png";
      } else {
        image.src = "RedLight.png";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I am confused on is:

Is this code using an array?
Also, what does it mean by the structure of the array?

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: First learn what [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is

Comment: An array looks like: `['green', 'red', '...']`, you should probably create an variable to hold the index and then moving the index

Comment: Please validate your HTML `<img id="RedLight.png" onclick "changeImage()" src="RedLight.png" width="200" height="300">` at https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me ( Click on the square ):

**Code on your case:**

```
// Remember to include jQuery first!
function switchLight() {
    var image = $('img');

    //the array, but is useless and no sense in this case
    var lightColor = ['GreenLight.png', 'AmberLight.png', 'RedLight.png']; // green orange red

    switch ( image.src ) {
      case lightColor[0]:
        image.setAttribute('src', lightColor[1]);
        break;
      case lightColor[1]:
        image.setAttribute('src', lightColor[2]);
        break;
      case lightColor[2]:
        image.setAttribute('src', lightColor[0]);
        break;
      default: // else if not 0, 1 or 2
        console.log('Light is off');
    }
  }
```

**General Snippet:**

```js
// Remember to include jQuery first!

function switchLight() {
    var color = $('#light').css('background-color');
    
    //the array
    var colors = ['rgb(0, 128, 0)', 'rgb(255, 165, 0)', 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'];
  
    switch (color) {
      case colors[0]:
        $('#light').css('background-color', colors[1] )
        $('button').css('color', colors[1]);
        $('button').css('border-color', colors[1]);

        console.log('light is now ' + color + '...');
        break;
      case colors[1]:
        $('#light').css('background-color', colors[2])
        $('button').css('border-color', colors[2]);
        $('button').css('color', colors[2]);
        console.log('light is now ' + color + '...');
        break;
      case colors[2]:
        $('#light').css('background-color', colors[0])
        $('button').css('color', colors[0]);
        $('button').css('border-color', colors[0]);

        console.log('light is now ' + color + '...');
        break;
      default:
        console.log('Light is off');
    }
  }
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}
#light {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="light" onclick="switchLight()"></div>
```

I suggest to learn what is an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) before asking how to use it!

Comment: What about the **array** part of the question?!

Comment: Added! Sorry i **forget** it!

Comment: Now that would be an answer which would put the OP in right track ;)

Comment: The only reason for using arrays is so that you can use an expression for the index. Code based on arrays that only uses numeric constants between the brackets is just nonsense...